# How can I add a >10, <100 clause to my program?

Tags: arrays, loops

I am to enter 5 numbers, between 10 and 100. As each number is read, the program must display it only if it's not a duplicate of a number already read. I have to provide for the "worst case" in which all five numbers are different. I have use the smallest possible array to solve this problem and display the complete set of unique values input after the user enters each new value.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make it so that the number is between 10 and 100. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IsDuplicate {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int array[] = new int [5];
    int size = 0; 
    int x;
    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 10 and 100: ");
        x = input.nextInt();
     
        
        if(size == 0 || newNumber(array, size, x)) {
            System.out.println("This is the first time "+ x +" has been entered.");
            array[size] = x;
            size++;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    System.out.println("The complete set of unique values entered is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Unique value" +(i+1)+ ": is " +array[i]);
        }
        
        
        
        
    }

    private static boolean newNumber(int y[], int size, int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
            if (y[i] == x) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this quite easily. All you have to do is adjust your for loop taking the inputs, and add in a check for the value of x to see if it is `!(x < 10) && !(x > 100)`.

If your program is supposed to ask for another number when an unacceptable value has been entered, then you will also need to subtract 1 from `i` to ensure you still get 5 numbers total.

```
if(size == 0 || newNumber(array, size, x) ) {
       if(!(x < 10) && !(x > 100))
       {
        System.out.println("This is the first time "+ x +" has been entered.");
        array[size] = x;
        size++;
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("The number you entered is outside the range of acceptable values.");
           i = i - 1;
       }
    }
```